# Oracle APEX : How to show error message in dynamic action

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to display a success/error message with a dynamic action but nothing is showing up.

Here is my code for the true condition of my action.

```
declare
   v_complete number;
begin
 select count(task_status) into v_complete from IT_TASK where TASK_STATUS != 3 AND REQUEST_ID = :P32_ID ;

 if v_complete > 0 then
    apex_application.g_print_success_message := '<span style="color:red">Not all Task are complete!</span>';
    rollback;
 end if;

 if v_complete = 0 then
    apex_application.g_print_success_message := '<span style="color:green">All Task are complete!</span>';
    rollback;
 end if;
end;
```

However, no message appears after my condition is met.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Have you tried managing exceptions? It is possible this is throwing an exception so never getting into either message conditions.

Comment: I don't believe using g_print_success_message is supported, nor relevant in this case. Perhaps utilise a notification plugin instead.

Answer (score 2):

`apex_application.g_print_success_message` is only used by the Apex engine when rendering the page - after the page has been rendered, any dynamic actions that change it will have no effect.

A simple way you might achieve your goal is to add a display-only item to your page, e.g. `P1_RESULT`, and in your dynamic action set its value. Your dynamic action could also show and/or hide the display item as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize v_complete to 0 when declaring

```
declare
   v_complete number := 0;
begin..
.......
```

Answer (score -1):

Run the query in sqlplus or sqldeveloper and see the results. Add a third condition for v_complete < 0 with a different message. Also, turn on debugging and see if it's getting to the true condition. Also, best practice is to avoid putting anonymous PL/SQL blocks into APEX apps. This should be in a stored function and called to enhance reuse and maintenance.